# Printing values that exist in more than one column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R as follows.

```
IP1     IP2      No packet
X       Y        8017  
Z       A        5019  
Y       B        8017
```

I want to print the values that occur in both the IP1 and IP2 column. For instance, in the above example Y. How do I do that in R?

Comment: `intersect(df$IP1, df$IP2)`

Comment: That works! Thank you :)